# 3 posts in one row, and then two posts in the next row etc

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I need some help to modify a Wordpress loop. I would like to have a layout where every 2nd row has 3 posts in instead of two. So i would like to achieve the following:

Output:
medium-6 large-6, medium-6 large-6,
medium-4 large-4, medium-4 large-4, medium-4 large-4,
 
medium-6 large-6, medium-6 large-6, 
medium-4 large-4, medium-4 large-4, medium-4 large-4
... etc

I have tried the following which works for the first row but goes out of sync after that.

many thanks.

```
 


    if ( have_posts() ) :

       $post_i = 0;

       /* Start the Loop */
       while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

       $post_i++;

       if(  ($post_i + 1 ) % 4 == 0 && $post_i > 0 )
       $post_class = 'medium-6 large-6'; 
       else if( ($post_i + 1 ) % 5 == 0 && $post_i > 0 )
       $post_class = 'medium-6 large-6'; 
       else $post_class = 'medium-4 large-4';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use even odd condition to show post like `2 posts, 3 posts, 2 posts, 3 posts ... etc`

```
if (have_posts()) :

    $post_i = 0;

    /* Start the Loop */
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        if ($post_i % 2 == 0)
            $post_class = 'medium-6 large-6'; 
        else
            $post_class = 'medium-4 large-4';

        var_dump($post_class);

        $post_i++;
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Output:

1. medium-6 large-6
2. medium-4 large-4
3. medium-6 large-6
4. medium-4 large-4
5. .....etc

Comment: Thanks for answering my question but I think I didnt explain myself very well. Im looking for an output that looks like this. 

Output:
medium-6 large-6, 
medium-6 large-6,
medium-4 large-4,
medium-4 large-4,
medium-4 large-4,
medium-6 large-6,
medium-6 large-6,
medium-4 large-4,
medium-4 large-4,
medium-4 large-4,
.....etc

Comment: you didn't said in the question

Comment: i think this was the confusing aspect of my question. "example: 2 posts 3 posts 2 posts 3 posts".

Comment: So no luck in figuring it out?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Probably not the best solution but it works for me. I did the follwoing:

```
        if (have_posts()) :

            $post_i = 0;

            /* Start the Loop */
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();



                    if ($post_i % 5 == 0)
                    $post_class = 'medium-6 large-6';                    
                else if ($post_i % 5 == 1)
                    $post_class = 'medium-6 large-6';

                else  $post_class = 'medium-4 large-4';


                $post_i++;

        var_dump($post_class); 


         endwhile;

        endif;
```